# What's required to create a tag synonym?

Tags: support, tags, reputation

I just created [hoard-of-the-dragon-queen](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hoard-of-the-dragon-queen) and think it would be a very good idea to add a synonym [hotdq](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotdq), considering how common that abbreviation is. However, when I go to suggest it, I'm told I need 5 score in that tag before I can suggest synonyms. That's fine, but... do I not already have 5 score in that tag, based on having added it to questions I've asked and/or answered? Or is the system specifically not counting my score because I created the tag myself (which would be weird)?

Or is it just like certain badges, etc., in that it takes a few minutes for the SE hamsters to run around and record that I do in fact have a score of 5, and I should just be patient?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a hamster thing. I've just now suggested it as a synonym myself just to check it had nothing to do with the [hotdq](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hotdq) tag not existing. [You do have an answer score of 5 in the tag](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/hoard-of-the-dragon-queen/synonyms) and meet the reputation prerequisite.

Comment: But please create synonyms in response to people mistagging, just making a bunch of them up is pointless complexity and waste.

Comment: Yeah we don't usually do anticipatory synonym creation -- if nobody's used it we don't really need a synonym for it.

Comment: Interesting, that's news to me. I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @mxyzplk What do you mean?  That is, what is the cost of a synonym?/What is wasted and where does the complexity come from?

Comment: Uh - work to set them up, maintenance when they conflict with something else in the future, more junk coming up in autocomplete when you're trying to find useful tags - the standard complexity that too much stuff provides in every other human endeavor. In general it's always a worst practice to overengineer up front.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Generally, yeah, we try to be conservative with synonyms. We'll *very rarely* do some obvious ones in anticipation of a need (actually I'm failing to come up with examples, but I feel like the number is slightly above zero), but as a rule it's more effective to create them reactively to duplicate tags being created, retagging projects being launched, and the like — real demonstrations of utility.

Comment: There was [spell to spells](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7518/make-spell-a-synonym-of-spells) recently, and there's some British/American English spelling synonyms.