# Make [spell] a synonym of [spells]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

several times i get this warning when tagging questions,

> you seem to be attempting to create the tag `[spell]` but the tag `[spells]` already exist. Did you meant to use `[spells]`?

Or something to that effect.

Can we get a synonym mapping?

Answer (score 9):

## Done!

Normally we don't make synonyms for plural forms and such because the system redirects people, as you found, but this is such a high-traffic tag that an exception is likely very useful.