# Add [feat] as a synonym for [feats]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

several times i get this warning when tagging questions,

> you seem to be attempting to create the tag [feat] but the tag [feats] already exist. Did you meant to use [feats]?

Or something to that effect.

Can we get a synonym mapping?

[© Ctrl+C Ctrl+V](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7518/make-spell-a-synonym-of-spells)

Answer (score 3):

Synonym added!

The same reasons [as wot SevenSideDie sed](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7519/1204).

By the way, after typing out a tag's name, you can press <kbd>↓</kbd> or <kbd>tab</kbd> to pick the first option in the autocomplete. With a tag like this it'll usually be the right one after just a couple of letters.